# Static files served by django in development and apache in production. Why not use same folder?

Tags: python, django, apache

Apologies in advance if this question is conceptual, but I just want to make sure I am not doing something that is a security risk or problematic in some other sense. My belief is that a django convention is redundant, and if this is not the case, my understanding is wrong.

When I develop in django (separate machine to production), I have django serve all the static files, which I put in the project directory in a folder called "static". On my production machine with DEBUG=False, I set up Apache to serve the static files from the SAME directory, and get Apache to turn off mod_python from this directory with the following in the httpd.conf virtual host for django served by apache:

```
# J1.7 turn off mod_python for the static direcotyr of binge and any
# url that ends in gif, jpg or png
<Location '/static/'>
    SetHandler None
</Location>

# The images to be served are in here
Alias /static/ /www/myserver/myproject/myproject/static/
<Directory /www/myserver/myproject/myproject/static>
    AllowOverride None
    Options -Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

On the development server, so I can serve my static files, I use:

```
# files to be served by production server are here
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# this is prefixed to any reference of a static file. the documentation says this
# should be the absolute URL of where the static files are served when on the 
# production server, and just the word /static/ for the development server NUTS!
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# files to be served by development server are here
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/www/myserver/myproject/myproject/static",
)
```

Now, Django tries to enforce that the development static directory, and the production static directory be in different places, as setting `STATIC_ROOT` to any of the directories in `STATICFILES_DIRS` flags an error.

I don't understand why this is forced. and also with `STATICFILES_DIRS' being a tuple, the assumption is that you are going to have static files all over your site/ This is something I also don't understand, because a django page can't refer to image files in a relative directory anyway. It has to be in some folder you determine as a location for django to serve it from, and you have to use

```
<script src="{% static "javascript/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" %}"></script>
```

rather than

```
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

I am missing the understanding of what advantage of putting static files in directories all over your project, then running `manage.py collect static` to gather them into a separate folder to be sftp'd to a location (probably in your project folder) to be served by apache.

Comment: I'm going to fix this a bit so that it doesn't get downvoted to hell and back...

Comment: I edited this already. Feel fee to add/change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sort of a throwback to the fact that by default, HTTPd structures URLs to mirror the underlying filesystem. It certainly is feasible to use a set of `Alias` directives to graft the various static asset subdirectories into the URL structure instead, and I have done just this on a few occasions. It's a bit more work on first deployment, but further revisions to the project require very few if any changes to the configuration, and no extra steps on deployment.